# Where is the mistake in this tail recursive Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I have to implement a sum function in Haskell in two ways. One function with tail recursion and the other without tail recursion.

Here is the one without tail recursion and it works perfectly

```
sum1 x = if x==0 then 0 else x + sum1(x-1)
```

Here is my attempt with tail recursion and it doesn't work:

```
sum2 x = help 0 y
help x y = if y==0 then x else help(x+y,y-1)
```

Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: Euh that's not the syntax for calling a function in Haskell.

Comment: You don't really have to care but it might be interesting to you that even the tail recursive variant consumes memory for each step. Because haskell is lazy this builds up a huge computation like `0+500000+499999+499998...` which is only executed after we are done recurring. The fix would be to use seq/bang patterns or use some other source of strictness like `foldl' (+) 0`.

Answer (score 5):

Your line:

```
help x y = if y==0 then x else help(x+y,y-1)
```

is not the correct syntax for calling a function. Because here the Haskell compiler will interpret it as:

```
help x y = if y==0 then x else help (x+y,y-1)
--                                  ^ a tuple
```

Instead you should write:

```
help x y = if y==0 then x else help (x+y) (y-1)
--                                  ^ two arguments
```

Furthermore you can also use guards, like:

```
helper x y | y == 0 = x
           | otherwise = help (x+y) (y-1)
```

Finally there is also an error in the first line of `sum2`. It should be `x` instead of `y`:

```
sum2 x = help 0 x
```

So in full, we get:

```
sum2 x = help 0 x
helper s x | x == 0 = s
           | otherwise = help (s+x) (x-1)
```

I also renamed `y` in the `helper` to `x` and `x` to `s` (as in `s`um) to make it less confusing (kudos to [@Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745611/where-is-the-mistake-in-this-tail-recursive-haskell-function/43745668?noredirect=1#comment74560618_43745668) for commenting on this).

Or use an *eta reduction*:

```
sum2 = help 0
```

Finally note that you do not need recursion for this. An implementation that would work faster is the following:

```
sum3 x = div (x*(x+1)) 2
```

Since:

```
 n
---
\       (n+1) n
/   i = -------
---        2
i=1
```

Comment: Thank you helped me a lot. We started recently with Haskell at the university and I am new to this functional programming.

Comment: It's confusing though to pass `x` to the `y` parameter.

Comment: @Bergi: Indeed. I did not take a look at the variable names. I modified the code.